# How to catch Android Firebase signUpWithEmailAndPassword error code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I see online in JavaScript documentation you can catch the error code returned from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function to determine whether it's a email already used, password too weak etc. How do I do this in Java?

This in JavaScript can tell which error it is.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`task.getException()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getException()) is the counterpart in Android for the *errorCode* you're looking for. The example in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/) shows it:

> **Sign up new users**
>
> Create a new `createAccount` method which takes in an email address and password, validates them and then creates a new user with the [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.
>
> ```
> mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
>     .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
>             Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
>
>             // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
>             // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
>             // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
>             if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
>                 Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
>                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>
>             // ...
>         }
>     });
> ```
>
> Add a form to register new users with their email and password and call this new method when it is submitted. You can see an example in our [quickstart sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth/app/src/main).

Answer (score 5):

see this code for your reference this might be the exact answer yo want, catch exception  if task not successful as shown in below code,

```
             mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mUserEmail, mPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, getString(R.string.log_message_auth_successful) + " createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // if task is not successful show error
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        try {
                            throw task.getException();
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                              // show error toast ot user ,user already exist

                            } catch (FirebaseNetworkException e) {
                            //show error tost network exception

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, R.string.log_error_occurred,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        // successfully account created
                        // now the AuthStateListener runs the onAuthStateChanged callback


                    }
                }

            });
```

Comment: comment if any problem occurs ,up vote if this help you

Comment: @Bobby you can mark this answer as accepted  if this is was exactly you want ,so that someone can easliy refer this answer having same problem.

Comment: Thanks man! This is also correct but I can't accept two answers:(

Comment: @Bobby you can unmark answer and select another if you prefer the new one is best answer.. Anyway  happy coding

Comment: Hi Sagar. Noticed that you've had been making too much *noise* on your answer being accepted. This is unneccessary and may annoy the OP if it continues. The answer you provided could be correct, but is also seen in the answer I posted. The only difference is that you inserted the `.getException()` in a try-catch statement and `throw` the exception, which is not needed since the `getException()` is the details the OP needs. Cheers!

Comment: Hi AL its not about accepting answer, The answer which i posted  consists of catching exact exception  and showing it to user and also by doing this we can also get to know which type of exception  occurs,  more precisely  it shows user collision or network exception.  In your code you only make a toast of user defined text message  to show exception occurs ,which is not the correct way of handling  exception.  And regarding the comment  i only gave solution  to asker that hi can unmark as well,  relax man.

Comment: Hi Sagar. All is cool. It's not exactly my code, its just from the docs. I didn't provide any addition to it since I'm fairly sure that a well rep user would know how to handle it. Just also pointed out that although it is acceptable, 3 *noise* comments is maybe a bit too much. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Al, I submitted answer according to what i learnt  before and how i am doing it in my code , if  asker knows how to  Solve issues he would not asked.  Anyway I apologise for the inconvenience cuased by me.